Book where alien craft land on Earth and allow people to be resurrected as missionaries of the aliens
I read this book a good 20 years ago it was at my dad's and he can't remember it.
Alien craft land all over Earth in shape of a triangle. (I think) Dead humans can be put in craft and brought back to life only to be missionaries for alien race and spread the word through the galaxy. You only know about alien race when you die and book is told through eyes of human who wants nothing to do with aliens so you never found out who or what they are.
Eventually humans start to commit suicide to be able to become missionaries, and the earth becomes depopulated. I have not been able to find book again and its really bugging me as I would like to read again.
The cover was a picture of the unusual triangle craft/obelisk.

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Hmmm. Sounds somewhat similar to Robert Charles Wilson's The Harvest. That book is from 1995 and the aliens offer immortality. One guy wants nothing to do with it.
